# Share on Facebook does not show thumbnail images

Tags: php, htaccess, images, facebook

I have a PHP application which has a "Share on Facebook" button that,

- On the development server shows the thumbnail images correctly and allows the user to select between them
- On the live server, it does NOT show the thumbnail images at all.

The relevant portion of the .htaccess file is:

```
# Set up caching on media files for 2 days
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv)$">
ExpiresDefault A172800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm using the exact same set of php files and .htaccess, but the server configuration is different.

What could be causing this? Note that the text appears fine.

**Edit1**

We are also doing some URL rewriting related to images in the .htaccess (on both servers):

```
...
RewriteRule ^.*/content/image/(.*)$ content/image/$1 [L]
...
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
...
```

Would that be somehow making a difference? Images appear fine all throughout the site.

(I posted this question earlier as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142597/share-on-facebook-does-not-show-thumbnail-images)
)

Comment: Can you view source on both servers and see if the paths are being re-written differently?

Comment: In addition to @Don's tip have you tried using Live HTTP Headers or Tamper Data (Firefox) or something like Charles Web Debugging Proxy to see what Facebook is actually requesting from both sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Facebook does not show the thumbnail is because it cannot fetch it. Why not try testing it once without the URL rewriting?

Comment: thanks - it started working after i removed the url rewriting bit

Answer (score 1):

Try testing using facebook's URL linter.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Make sure Facebooks bot can access the page.

Try implementing the open graph protocol to asset facebook in choosing an image.

Also, keep in mind that facebook caches pages for a period of time, if the linter is working but images are still no showing when using like and share this could be the problem.